# How to get the Message Id from POP3 using java Mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

From the url

> https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html,

You can also pre-fetch all the UIDs for all messages like this:

```
FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
folder.fetch(folder.getMessages(), fp);
```

Then use the technique above to get the UID for each message. This is similar to the technique used with the UIDFolder interface supported by IMAP, but note that POP3 UIDs are strings, not integers like IMAP UIDs. See the POP3 spec for details.

From this, `https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt,`

In number 7, there's an example of what I need.

Examples:

```
         S: +OK POP3 server ready <1896.697170952@dbc.mtview.ca.us>
         C: APOP mrose c4c9334bac560ecc979e58001b3e22fb
         S: +OK maildrop has 1 message (369 octets)

         In this example, the shared  secret  is  the  string  `tan-
         staaf'.  Hence, the MD5 algorithm is applied to the string

            <1896.697170952@dbc.mtview.ca.us>tanstaaf

         which produces a digest value of

            c4c9334bac560ecc979e58001b3e22fb //this is what we need in Java
```

After this, how do we get the MessageID / UID of each message?

Sample Message ID that I need. A fuego.mail Library that was deprecated was providing us this before:

```
<F855F5879C6E754E9DE37F2E7D0762327C942B43@GADC-EMB099.ap.abc‌​.com>
```

**UPDATE**
I got a 3 digit integer i.e. 561 when using this

```
Store store = emailSession.getStore(MAILSTORETYPE);

            store.connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
            emailFolder.fetch(emailFolder.getMessages(), fp);

            POP3Folder pf =(POP3Folder)emailFolder;         

            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];

                    String uid = pf.getUID(message);
                    System.out.println(uid);
```

Comment: Ok, you have copied an extract of jamavail doc related to UID of messages that can be used when the server supports the optional command `UIDL`, and an extract of RFC1939 related to `APOP` authentication. **What is your question exactly**? How to build the `APOP` digest or how to get message UIDs. They are totally unrelated. With no further details this question is *unclear*.

Comment: Note that the [JavaMail POP3 provider supports APOP](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html#mail.pop3.apop.enable), if that's what you're after.  Note also the POP3 UIDs are different than the Message-ID header in a message.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I need to get the Message ID of a mail in a POP3 Protocol Mailbox using Java.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added this references as they were the product of my research. I thought that they will lead to the solution.

Comment: The first part (javamail javadoc) should lead to the solution. Did you try do code it? But be aware that as said by BillShannon what you will get may not be what you expect: POP3 UIDL are unrelated to the Message-ID header.

Comment: folder.fetch(folder.getMessages(), fp); Where shall I get the Message ID here? folder.getMessages().getUID?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I dont see any getUID method in message

Comment: I got a 3 digit integer using getUID. I need a hex value like <F855F5879C6E754E9DE37F2E7D0762327C942B43@GADC-EMB099.ap.abc.com>

Comment: what you are looking for is a Message-ID. you would get that in Mail Headers